# Display sum of greatest integer in angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, subtotal

I am trying to create a directive to find sum of largest integer in the response data.

**directive:-**

```
.filter('sumByKey', function() {
        return function(data, key) {
            if (typeof(data) === 'undefined' || typeof(key) === 'undefined') {
                return 0;
            }

            var sum = 0;
            for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                sum += parseInt(data[i][key]);
            }

            return sum;
        };
```

In the above I am able to do  sum of total values present in the `data`.
There is a javascript function to calculate to find largest value and do sum of largest value *example:-*

```
var array = [5, 5, 7,7,8,8];
var max = array[0], total = 0;
array.forEach((a)=>{
  if(a==max){
    total+=max;
  }
  else if(a>max){
    max = total = a;
  }
});
console.log("total:"+total);
```

So here `data` is my `array` . Want to do same calculation. I tried to implement that on *directive* , but getting error.

**EDIT:-**

```
.filter('sumByKey', function() {
        return function(data, key) {
            if (typeof(data) === 'undefined' || typeof(key) === 'undefined') {
                return 0;
            }

            for(let child of data.DeploymentTime) {
            console.log(child);
            var i = child;
            var array = [].slice.call(i);
            var max = array, total = 0;
            array.forEach((a)=>{
              if(a==max){
                total+=max;
              }
              else if(a>max){
                max = total = a;
              }
            });

            return total;
        });
```

I am getting `is not iterable` javascript error

Comment: what is the error you are getting ? kindly post your final version of code to revise

Comment: @HanyHabib Not getting any error exactly , showing the max value and was counting the n-1 value. final version which is the one that I have posted for now .

Comment: @whoAml how this is your final version, where is the integration between the filter method and the second one

Comment: @HanyHabib I scrapped my code as it was not correct. I am confused with the process.

Comment: create your final plunker and i will update your code to make it work.

Comment: But my advice this is not the target of filters, filters is to mutate the data from one shap to another like date format or apply conditions.

Comment: @HanyHabib I got you , but this is complex as why I am doing this in directive. I will get back to you with my edits.

Comment: @HanyHabib i have added code in my EDIT. This is showing 0 value.

Comment: i edited your code to be simple and achieve your target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code, you are doing a lot of stuff which is mainly not required here below an example of working filter that achieves your requirement :

```
app.controller('demo', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.value = $filter('sumByKey')([{age:1},{age:2},{age:2}],'age'); 
})

app.filter('sumByKey', function() {
  return function(input,key) {

     if (typeof(input) === 'undefined' || typeof(key) === 'undefined') {
                return 0; 
      }

    var total = 0,max = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER;
     angular.forEach(input,function(a){
              if(a[key]==max){
                total+=max;
              }
              else if(a[key]>max){
                max = total = a[key]; 
              }
            });

     return total;
  }
});
```